# Running a function every time specific function type is run

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have 50 functions in my project. 10 of these functions are standard functions, while 40 of the functions all need to:

- Do their unique thing
- Then do another thing identical for all 40 functions (E.g. prepare some visual data for a render cycle)

As an example written in js syntax:

```
    const functionOne = () => {
        //Do my thing
        prepareRenderData()
    }

    const functionTwo = () => {
        //Do my thing
        prepareRenderData()
    }
    
    const functionThree...
```

Is there a method in JavaScript where I can make this prepareRenderData call implicit in the function, ultimately saving up towards 40 lines of code in this case?

Comment: yes, instead of calling this function in every component you can call these function in your root component and store it's data into context or redux store to use it.
and react have a plus point to load component by  lazy loading so the best way is to call function in specific component to make application fast.

Comment: First of all, this is not React syntax but Standard JS, second, you could use decorators, but then you have to assign them or thirs, you ran the prepareRenderData after calling those functions. But there's no implicit calling of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that you should go for this because of potential saving of 40 lines of code, but it is achievable by wrapper function like that:

```js
const getPreparedFunction = (fn) => {
  return () => {
      fn();

      console.log('General stuff is happening');
  };
}
    

const functionOne = getPreparedFunction(() => {
    console.log('I am functionOne');
});

const functionTwo = getPreparedFunction(() => {
    console.log('I am functionTwo');
});

functionOne();

functionTwo();
```

If you need the functions to get parameters and return stuff, you could change `getPreparedFunction` to:

```js
const getPreparedFunction = (fn) => {
  return (...args) => {
    const result = fn(...args);

    console.log('General stuff is happening');

    return result;
  };
};
```